# SQL: Double if statement/database query issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm a bit of a rookie to SQL and PHP coding, but am trying to do the following:

In order to prevent a logged-in user from entering a competition twice, I log their userid and the competition id (*comp*) to an SQL table, called *competitions*. When a user loads the page I'd like to be able to query the database to check to see if this userid has entered the particular competition before. If they have, it displays one version of the page, if they haven't it displays a second.

Basically, I'm looking to see if *userid==x* AND *comp==y* are in a given row in the table.

This is the code I've got so far, and it doesn't appear to be working.

```
$result = databaseSelect("select id, userid, comp from competitions where userid=" . $_SESSION['user']);

 if (count($result) > 0) {
 $r2 = ("select" . $result['id'] . " from" . $result . " where" . $result['comp'] . " == " . $compid);
 if (count($r2) > 0) {
 echo "<p>No competitions</p>";
 }
 else{

 echo "<p>Competition...</p>";
 }
```

Comment: First of all try adding some padding to `" where"` statement.

Comment: Hardy: Could you give an example of the padding you mean?

Comment: he means adding a space after 'from' and after 'where' so your query doesn't end up looking like "select something fromsomeplace wheresomevalue == 2"

Comment: I've now got the code sort of working, in that it actually displays something on the page. However, even when `$compid` is a totally unique number that no user has entered, it still acts as if there is a value greater than 0 in `$r2`.

When `echo`ing `$r2`, I get this displayed: _select fromArray where = 3_

Comment: Then another thing; what exactly does your databaseSelect query return? a resource? an array? 

Your second... "query" has issues as mentioned above. Plus, you don't actually DO anything with it. You just define a string (the query) and then count the amount of characters in that string. Since there are > 0 characters in that string, you'll always see "No competitions"... You should _run_ that query as well if you really want an anwwer.

Comment: `$result` is an array with anything from 0 rows to inf. and 3 columns.

Comment: Tularis: how do I run the query as well? Sorry for the stupid questions!

Comment: I would hazard by running it through your selectDatabase() function.

Comment: Got it sorted now. Managed to do away with the multiple IF loops and get an AND working in the original WHERE statement. Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: padding means you've got `... wherefoo==bar`, which is outright wrong because it should be `where foo=bar`: a space between `where` and `foo`, and a SINGLE `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look to see if the user has entered in a given competition with the id $comp_id. If there is a result it means the user has already entered in the competition.

```
$result = databaseSelect("select id, userid, comp from competitions where userid=" . $_SESSION['user'] . " AND comp=" . $comp_id );

if (count($result) > 0) {
    echo "You have already entered this competition";
} 
else {
    echo "This is the competition...";
}
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. That works! Think I tried that before but was missing the padding around the AND, or something like that, so it wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
//This will return a row if $_SESSION['user'] already has a competition with $compid 
$result = databaseSelect("select id, userid, comp from competitions where userid=" . $_SESSION['user'] ." AND comp = ". $compid);
if (count($result) > 0) {
  // user already partecipates to the competition 
}
else{
  //ok, you can partecipate
}
```